# Copy Dynamic Struct Array into another C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, struct

I'm not that good in English, that's why my Question is probably wrong. But I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it or if it's even possible to do.

I have 2 Structs defined:

```
typedef struct
{
  UINT16        ScriptNumber;
  std::string   ScriptText;
} StepStruct;


typedef struct
{
  std::string               SequenceName;
  std::string               DisplayName;
  StepStruct                SequenceSteps;
} SequenceStruct;
```

As you can see, the first Struct is a Member of the second struct. So I want both structs to by dynamical. So I created 2 Dynamic Arrays from the Type `StepStruct` and 1 dynamic Array from the Type `SequenceStruct`.

The two dynamical Arrays for of the Type *StepStructs* are defined as follows:

```
StepStruct gsFirstSkript[] =
{    
  { 1 , "SkriptText One"},
  { 2 , "SkriptText Two"},
  { 45, "SkriptText Three"}
}

StepStruct gsSecondSkript[] =
{    
  { 48, "SkriptText One"},
  { 2 , "SkriptText Two"},
  { 45, "SkriptText Three"}
}
```

Those to Structs are of the Type `StepStruct`. Now I want to do the Same with a `SequenceStruct` Type, but I want to assign the two Arrays I already have to it under the Struct Member `SequenceSteps`. I mean this as follows:

```
SequenceStruct gsSequenceList[] =
{    
  { "FirstScript", "Test One", gsFirstSkript},
  { "SecondScript", "Test Two", gsSecondSkript}
}
```

If I now want to Read the Member *gsSequenceList*, I can not access any information under the *SequenceSteps* Index of it! What means, that the Data is not copied! I tried it with Pointers
but had no success.

```
UINT16 lTestVal = gsSequenceList[0].SequenceSteps[2].ScriptNumber;
```

So Can I mangage that this works, and lTestVal contains the Value 45?

Comment: You don't have any dynamic struct arrays in your code. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: `SequenceStruct gsSequenceList[] = {{ "FirstScript", "Test One", gsFirstSkript}, ...};` Isn't right.  You're initialising the inner struct with an array of structs.. It does not take an array at all. It takes only ONE.  `gsFirstSkript` & `gsSecondSkript` are both arrays.

Comment: From what I'm guessing, he's trying to do exactly that - store a dynamic list in a field of a struct. Thats not possible the way you do it, you have to use a complex data structure like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef struct
{
  std::string               SequenceName;
  std::string               DisplayName;
  StepStruct*               SequenceSteps;
} SequenceStruct;
```

This will allow the code to compile and the test fragment you've shown will work.
However this will not copy the data. If you change `gsFristSkript` it will change in gsSequenceList as well. If you want to make a copy of the data you can either do that explicitly, have a constructor or just use vector<>.
Here's the solution with vector:

```
#include <vector>
...
typedef struct{
  std::string               SequenceName;
  std::string               DisplayName;
  vector<StepStruct>        SequenceSteps;
} SequenceStruct;

vector<StepStruct> gsFirstSkript =
{    
  { 1 , "SkriptText One"},
  { 2 , "SkriptText Two"},
  { 45, "SkriptText Three"}
}

vector<StepStruct> gsSecondSkript =
{    
  { 48, "SkriptText One"},
  { 2 , "SkriptText Two"},
  { 45, "SkriptText Three"}
}

SequenceStruct gsSequenceList[] =
{    
  { "FirstScript", "Test One", gsFirstSkript},
  { "SecondScript", "Test Two", gsSecondSkript}
}
```